# Does Manchester United have 659 million fans worldwide?

Tags: football

According to the [Manchester United football club](http://www.manutd.com/en/News-And-Features/Club-News/2012/May/manchester-united-global-following-confirmed-as-659million.aspx?pageNo=1), they had 659 million followers worldwide in 2012.

> Manchester United has 659 million followers worldwide:
>
> - 71 million in Americas
> - 90 million in Europe
> - 173 million in Africa and the Middle East
> - 325 million in Asia

In 2011, [*The Times*](http://www.thetimes.co.uk/tto/sport/football/premierleague/article3192868.ece) reported a smaller number:

> A confidential club-by-club analysis obtained by The Times shows that United 
>   have nearly five times as many overseas supporters as Liverpool and more 
>   than twice the figure for the next popular club.
>
> The Barclays Premier League champions command a following of 354 million

This number was [repeated by the BBC](http://www.bbc.com/sport/0/football/20974695).

How many followers does Manchester United have?

Comment: This question appears to conflate the ideas of following a football team versus following a Twitter account. Please clarify before we let people try to answer this.

Comment: @Oddthinking, 655 million followers means that one in every ten persons in the world supports Manchester United. In perspective, the number of Twitter followers are one hundredth of that number. This seems odd to me. So I was wondering how credible these numbers were. Perhaps you can rephrase the question for me.

Comment: @Oddthinking, I would like to know the total number of United fans worldwide. The numbers stated seem to make no sense.

Comment: I removed the Twitter statistic as confusing (to get as many as 1 in 100 fans to follow you on Twitter seems extraordinarily high to me, but spam bots obscure the real figures), added some more context and re-opened.

Comment: Frankly, have two different estimates, by two different companies (Sport+Markt vs Kantar),  about a year apart, differing *only* by a factor of 2, seems pretty reasonable. I don't know what more you are hoping to get. (Sure, we could get details of methodologies, or more up-to-date estimates, but would that help?)

Comment: @Oddthinking, This seems reasonable. I would like to know accurate the number is.

Comment: In my opinion this question is still too vague. Can you clearly specify what you mean by `fan/follower/supporter`?